# Comparing two dates with different formats

Tags: r, datetime

I need to compare two dates for the following dataset:

```
structure(list(date = c(20160919L, 20161108L, 20160217L), TagActivationDate = structure(c(24L, 
42L, 9L), .Label = c("1/10/2016", "1/11/2016", "10/10/2016", 
"10/11/2016", "11/08/2016", "11/10/2016", "11/11/2016", "12/10/2016", 
"12/11/2016", "13/10/2016", "13/11/2016", "14/10/2016", "14/11/2016", 
"15/10/2016", "16/10/2016", "17/10/2016", "18/10/2016", "19/08/2016", 
"19/10/2016", "2/10/2016", "20/10/2016", "21/10/2016", "22/10/2016", 
"23/09/2016", "23/10/2016", "24/09/2016", "24/10/2016", "25/09/2016", 
"25/10/2016", "26/10/2016", "27/10/2016", "28/09/2016", "28/10/2016", 
"29/09/2016", "29/10/2016", "3/10/2016", "30/09/2016", "30/10/2016", 
"31/10/2016", "4/10/2016", "5/10/2016", "5/11/2016", "6/10/2016", 
"6/11/2016", "7/11/2016", "8/10/2016", "8/11/2016", "9/10/2016", 
"9/11/2016"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", "TagActivationDate"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

One of them is integer and another one is factor, I need to label them if they have more than two days difference:

```
mydata$filtcases <- mydata$date >= ( mydata$TagActivationDate - 2)
```

I tried to converting them to different formats but none of them were successful. Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: So the expected output is `TRUE` for all of them?

Comment: In this example yes

Comment: Convert both to same date format, then get difference.

Comment: `library(lubridate); abs(ymd(x$date) - dmy(x$TagActivationDate)) > 2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @zx8754 mentioned, try getting both of them in the same format and then find the difference between them

```
abs(as.Date(as.character(df$date), "%Y%m%d") - 
                as.Date(as.character(df$TagActivationDate), "%d/%m/%Y")) > 2
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Using lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)

mydata$filtcases <- abs(ymd(mydata$date) - dmy(mydata$TagActivationDate)) > 2
```